# Is it possible to use the same session variable on the index and a underpage without cookies?

Tags: php, session

I try to use the same session variable I created in localhost/project/underpages/page.php in localhost/project/index.php.

But if I check with var_dump it says null so there must be something wrong.

page.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    header("Location: ../index.php?logged-in");
?>
```

index.php

```
  <?php
        session_start();
        var_dump $_SESSION['loggedin'];
    ?>
```

I thougt now must be written true and not null.

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean, `without cookies`? If there are no cookies, you need to pass the session id in the url otherwise the server has no way to relate both requests.

Comment: So I should use the GET-method?

Comment: You already are. Why no cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try your code and it works fine...
When you go on localhost/project/underpages/page.php
It redirect you to localhost/project/index.php?logged-in
and then I got this statement `path/index.php:3:boolean true`

I just notice that u use  `var_dump $_SESSION['loggedin'];` without "()", so you need to use `var_dump($_SESSION['loggedin']);`, I hope that this will resolve your problem

Comment: I tried now with only this few lines of the code i printet befor in the question. i get this: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ScreenProject2\screen-projekt\sessiontest\index.php on line 3`

Comment: Yeap u need to var_dump have () so you need to put statement into it.
var_dump($_SESSION['loggedin']); like that :)